# Recent Files when Attaching Documents with Mac

Tags: macbook-pro

I have the same problem when attaching files to emails in Outlook on my Mac.  The answer that was provided to the same question, did not work. I quit Outlook and started it up again, but this did not solve the problem.  When I open Finder, the recent files includes all of the files that I have been working on.  However, when I'm in outlook and want to attach a file to the email, the recent files are old files that I've worked on a couple months ago.  Is there a way to refresh these files or change the properties of what is displayed etc.?  Like the other user who asked the question, after having just worked on a document that I want to attach, I have to click on "brown this Mac" and go through the folders until I get to my document.
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `the same problem` same as what? `the same question` what question?

Comment: My bad.  I thought that my questions was a continuation of a previous question that everyone could see the trail.  When I use Outlook on my MacBook Pro, and click the paper clip to attach a file, the options are: Browse this Mac; Browse Cloud Locations; Insert Hyperlink and then below those options, it shows Recent Files.  When I'm on my Windows PC, the Recent Files will show the documents that I just finished updating and then I'm able to select that to include in the email.  However, with the Mac, these files are old files and don't refresh.  Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: *I thought that my questions was a continuation of a previous question* - this is your only question ... how is it a continuation?

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site. There's only one question on this page: yours. Keep that in mind when asking. You can edit your question and include a link for the context. Or you can explain what you've tried to us. But whatever you do use the EDIT button to make your question better.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum & is not threaded like one. Unless you provide a specific link to the QA to which you are referring, no-one will ever be able to trace it.